# How to fix PhpStorm Persian/Arabic font?

Tags: fonts, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.3.2 and Persian font is unreadable. How to change Persian font in this IDE ?

[image]

Comment: is  there any way to change only Parsian/Arabic font ? not hole fonts .. other fonts mostly do not support these type of language.

Comment: What font is that? Try setting another font (sadly you cannot select different font for Arabic/Persian symbols only). For example: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/ (https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2020/01/15/jetbrains-mono-a-new-font-made-for-developers/) or whatever other font you like that supports your language (e.g. Consolas may be good if you are on Windows). P.S. If you google "JetBrains mono" you will find multiple articles about it and possible alternatives that other people are using (usually in comments)

Comment: so .. is there any way to declare new font in IDE that exsists in local system ? @LazyOne

Comment: 1) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Font` -- that's where you select the master font. Then at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Color Scheme Font` you can override font if needed that will be specific to that color scheme only. 2) IDE lists fonts provided by your OS. 3) Some fonts may not be listed if "Show monospaced fonts only" is selected .. as some fonts may not provide such flag for some reason...

Comment: Contact JetBrains Support from the Help menu -- they know more how their product work and may offer better assistance/suggestions. But changing font just for Arabic/Persian or any other alphabet -- don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `settings/Editor/Font` for Arabic/Parsian font .. we shouldn't force IDE to use monospaced Fonts.

1. so just simply remove `show only monospaced fonts` checkbox.
2. choose your desire font in font input 
   (This is A font to implements on most fonts in code that can render correctly.)
3. now if rendering font fails IDE will implement other font by setting `Fallback Font`.

you can see results in this image :
[image]